# How do I read sms(inbox) and update them in my app in real time in Android

Tags: android, sms

I have successfully been able to retrieve SMS and display them in my app but I want them to update automatically as they are received. Any help?
here is my code

```
public void refreshSmsInbox() {
    ContentResolver contentResolver =getContentResolver();
    Cursor smsInboxCursor = contentResolver.query(Telephony.Sms.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
    int totalSMs;
    int Id = adapter.getItemCount();
    if (Id >= 0) {
    if (smsInboxCursor != null) {
        totalSMs = smsInboxCursor.getCount();
        if (smsInboxCursor.moveToFirst()) {
            for (int j = 0; j < totalSMs; j++) {
                 indexBody = smsInboxCursor.getString(smsInboxCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(Telephony.Sms.BODY));
                 indexAddress = smsInboxCursor.getString(smsInboxCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(Telephony.Sms.ADDRESS));
                 indexDate = smsInboxCursor.getString(smsInboxCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(Telephony.Sms.DATE));
                dateFormat = new Date(smsInboxCursor.getShort(0));
                smsModel.add(new SmsModel(Id, indexAddress, indexBody, dateFormat.toString(), messageSender));
                adapter.setSmsModel(smsModel);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
                recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
                smsInboxCursor.moveToNext();
            }
            }
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "No message to show", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Cound use the SMS_RECEIVED broadcast:

```
<receiver
        android:name=".MsgReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"></action>

        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

new MsgReceiver.class under the package:

```
public class MsgReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // TODO: This method is called when the BroadcastReceiver is receiving
    // an Intent broadcast.
    Toast.makeText(context, "sms change", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    // refreshSmsInbox
    
}}
```

could also dynamicly registrat the broadcast SMS_RECEIVED.

Comment: hi @Anna Thanks for your answer.So i tried implementing the resheshSmsInbox method in my receiver class but still doesn't work.i have to exit app for it to update

Comment: Did you see the toast when the sms changed?  Could add a log or debug to the var totalSMs  to see Whether the number of SMs changes. @louis hugo

Answer (score 0):

try use ContentObserver to get the change of sms. follow is a example:

```
public class TestActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    refreshSmsInbox("");
    getContentResolver().registerContentObserver(Uri.parse("content://sms"),
            true,
            new MyObserver(new Handler()));
}

private final class MyObserver extends ContentObserver {
    public MyObserver(Handler handler) {
        super(handler);
    }

    @Override
    public void onChange(boolean selfChange) {
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox"),
                null, null, null, null);
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.append("address=").append(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("address")));
            sb.append(";subject").append(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("subject")));
            sb.append(";body").append(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("body")));
            sb.append(";time").append(cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex("date")));
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "sms change", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            refreshSmsInbox(new String(sb));
        }
    }
}

public void refreshSmsInbox(String s) {
    ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
    Cursor smsInboxCursor = null;
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        smsInboxCursor = contentResolver.query(Telephony.Sms.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
        int totalSMs;
        int Id = 0;
        if (Id >= 0) {
            if (smsInboxCursor != null) {
                totalSMs = smsInboxCursor.getCount();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "sms change count " + totalSMs + " msg:" + s, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                if (smsInboxCursor.moveToFirst()) {
                }
            }
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "No message to show", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}}
```